# How to extract a list of names that start with an ‘s’ and end with a ‘p’ in input_list using filter() function in PYTHON?

Tags: python-3.x, startswith, ends-with, filterfunction

```
input_list =  ['soap','sharp','shy','silent','ship','summer','sheep']
```

Extract a list of names that start with an `s` and end with a `p` (both 's' and 'p' are lowercase) in `input_list` using `filter` function.

Output should be:

```
['soap', 'sharp', 'ship', 'sheep']
```

Comment: sp = list(filter(lambda x: x[0:].startswith('s') and x[-1].endswith('p'),input_list ))

print(sp)

Answer (score 3):

```py
input_list = ['soap', 'sharp', 'shy', 'silent', 'ship', 'summer', 'sheep']

sp = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 's' and x[-1]=='p', input_list))

print(sp)
```

Comment: An alternative to the second line that some might find a little more readable:

```sp = [w for w in input_list if w.startswith('s') and w.endswith('p')]```

Answer (score 2):

`sp = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("s") and x.endswith("p"), input_list))`

`print(sp)`

This would give you the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Here how's it can be done easily-

```
input_list =  ['soap','sharp','shy','silent','ship','summer','sheep']


def fil_func(name):
    if name[0]=='s' and name[-1]=='p':
        return True

correct_name = []
for i in input_list:
    name = list(filter(fil_func, input_list)) # list() is added because filter function returns a generator.
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("s") and x.endswith("p"), input_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sp = list(filter(lambda x:x[0]=='s' and x[-1]=='p',input_list))


print(sp)
```

Comment: Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sp = list(filter(lambda word: (word[0]=="s") and (word[-1]=="p"), input_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

It can easily be done using the following code sample:

```
input_list =  ['soap','sharp','shy','silent','ship','summer','sheep']

sp = list(filter(lambda x:x[0]=='s' and x[-1]=='p', input_list)) 

print(sp)
```

Comment: Best not to copy answers. There is already one just like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66231324/11603043